# Is there way to persist the objects in RMI, so that it reload on restart

Tags: rmi, rmiregistry

Is there way to persist the objects in RMIregistry service so that it reload on restart? in latest version 1.7 Java rte. Example : corba naming service persists the bind service information and reloads in case it is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

You've just described RMI Activation. That's exactly what it does.

**EDIT** This answer applies to the original version of the question. The answer to the current version is 'no', unless you write something yourself, which isn't hard. But it would also be pointless unless you also used Activation.

Or you could use LDAP instead of the Registry, but you'd still need Activation for it to make sense.

Comment: Please check my updated question . I am resposible for rmiregistry service. the one which holds the rmi data in cache. the service goes down , the dependent applicition needs to rebind .i.e. restart.

Comment: You don't need the RMI Registry after the initial lookup with Activation. Just persist the stub, and it will resurrect itself on next usage.

Comment: Well that is true from application point of view , but if the registry service crashes and restarts , any application previously registered will be cleaned up. And app will get object not bound exception on resolve .

Comment: @VinayTiwari I can only repeat what I said. You don't need the Registry after the intial lookup. As a matter of fact you don't need it at all in Activation. You just persist the stub resulting from the intial setup, and load it every time you start the application, from wherever you persisted it. I don't know what 'true from the application point of view' might mean, as opposed to 'true'.

Comment: And I've never seen an RMI Registry crash, after using it since 1997.